# Reading Ireland baptism record from 1826?

Tags: birth-records, ireland, 1820s

[image]

This is the baptism for Jacobus (James) Fleming and Maria (Mary) Dwyer’s daughter, Juliana. Juliana was baptized in the Sologhead Catholic Parish on 18 September 1826. Godparent: Honora. But I can't read the last word or words. It looks like "Brown John" but that doesn't make sense to me.

Can anyone read this?

Juliana’s baptism is the 2nd entry up from the bottom of the right-hand baptism register page at:
https://registers.nli.ie/registers/vtls000632757#page/38/mode/1up

Comment: [Brownjohn](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownjohn) is a real, if uncommon, surname.

Comment: Good point but no Brownjohn's in the Ireland census from 1901 and 1911, so unlikely.

Comment: A quick search of Ancestry etc shows a handful of Brownjohns in Ireland in the 19th century, and a few more born in Ireland but living in England. So it's not impossible that her surname is Brownjohn. But it could also be Brown(e), followed by another word. Have you looked forward and back in that register to see if a similar looking surname crops up again?